About bisexuality
My question is that one of my friend recently became bi after a break up with his cousin. the reason he became bi is because of a guy that guy was already gay so he targeted my friend .after two months of my friend's break up he comes in relationship with this guy he wasn't bi he is being manipulated by this guy bcs he was abnormally kind to my friend.they were not even friends they met through mutuals and then after meeting that guy Started becoming close to my friend I've tried thousand times to make him understand and my friend knows that he is wrong and all this thing is Haram but he still wants to do this bcs that guy treat him like a prince unlike my friends parents .so please tell me what should I do I will do his counselling one last time bcs he recently told me he wants future with this guy so tell me Shaikh should I cut him from my life bcs I've done his counselling more than his mother and I don't want to support him in his wrong decision so tell me what I should I do.

Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem
As Salaamu 3laykum,
I hope you and your family are doing well. MashALLAAH for helping this person. I would continue to try to help him or atleast be a part of his life so he may continue receive guidance. It doesn't have to be every week but perhaps every month or so?
Furthermore, we have to remember we are only here to guide, teach and convey and after that it is up to ALLAAH (Glory Be To HIM). That is the nature of this life.
I will say if you can atleast have your friend join you to come to the masjid or to attend a circle of Islamic learning in your community. Because having good company has an effect on people. And if he doesn't agree then maybe if he is willing to sit with an Islamic scholar/imam locally. These things are better in person. And you to remind him that shaitan gives thoughts and these thoughts are meant to stray people away from Islam.
I dont mind giving counsel on the side if you want to message on the side on this site.

Have a Nice Day!

Note #1: If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.
Note #2: This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.

According to Quran people have free will:

إِنَّا هَدَيْنَاهُ السَّبِيلَ إِمَّا شَاكِرًا وَ إِمَّا كَفُورًا
Surely We guided him upon the way whether he be thankful or unthankful
(76:3)

So, you can guide him in the right direction, but the final decision is up to him.
